# Best way to link objects for report

Tags: soql, reporting, custom-report-type, joined-reports

I am struggling to build a report that links and Opportunity to a Contact to a custom object.  Here are the basics:

Opportunities are actually jobs and the account id is the business.  Each opp has a custom field named Particpant__c [lookup(contact)] that links the Opportunity (in this case a job) to the person who has the position (Participant__c).  I then have a custom table (Dogs__c) that assigns each Contact to their dogs (Master[Contact]-Detail[Dogs__c]).  For instance:

Acme Vet (Account) would have a Thursday job (Opportunity) for Bob Loblaw to walk four dogs.

What I can't seem to sort out in Salesforce or SOQL is how to run a report that shows Opportunities, Contacts (Participant__c) and Dogs so that I could see:

**Opportunity**       **Participant**       **Dog**
Thursday Job      Bob Loblaw           Sissy
Thursday Job      Bob Loblaw           Missy
Thursday Job      Bob Loblaw           Prissy

Obviously, I would prefer to summarize as
Thursday Job      Bob Loblaw           Sissy, Missy, Prissy
But I'll take what I can get :)  I've taken a look at joined reporting and creating a new report type, but I can't seem to get the right combo of things to make the report work.  I know in SQL/MySQL this would be along the lines of:

SELECT Opportunity.Name, Contact.Firstname, Contact.Lastname, Dogs__c.Name 
FROM Opportunity JOIN Dogs__c ON Opportunity.Particpant__c = Dogs__c.Contact_ID__c

But I'm baffled as to how to make it work here.

Thanks,
KMT

Answer (score 1):

A custom report type whose base object is Opportunity can reference both Account (lookup) and the Contact (participant lookup). However, it can't go down from Contact to Dogs.

One workaround to this would be to have an after insert/update/delete/undelete trigger on Dogs that rolled up all Dogs on a given Contact into a Text Area Long field on Contact. This new field, say `RSF Dogs' then becomes available to the custom report type and you can then create your report to show lines like:

Thursday Job    Bob Loblaw    Sissy, Missy, Prissy

Assuming you are au fait with APEX triggers, there are numerous examples that can be located by googling. The estimable @sfdcfox has a good one here: https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/ForumsMain?id=906F00000008yWuIAI